# DAO class cannot be cast

Tags: java, spring

I've CourseDetailsDAO and BeanDAO. I'm getting

```
university.BeanDAO cannot be cast to university.CourseDetailsDAO
    at CourseDetailsBean.performLookup(CourseDetailsBean.java:49)
    at CourseDetailsBean.CoursedetailsAction(CourseDetailsBean.java:38)
```

those lines are :

CourseDetailsBean.java:49
 `CourseDetailsDAO helper = (CourseDetailsDAO) apc.getBean("courseDetailsDao");`

and

CourseDetailsBean.java:38
`performLookup(cID, cName, cDuration, cEligibility, cFee);`

BeanDAO

```
public List getStudent() {
List<Student> students = null;
    try
        {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from university.Student");
            students = (List<Student>)q.list();
```

CourseDetailsDAO

```
public List getcourseByName(String courseName) {
    List<Coursedetails> courselist = null;
    try
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Coursedetails.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("coursename", courseName));
        courselist = (List<Coursedetails>) criteria.list();
        tx.commit();
```

but I noticed that server has few warnings and may those are predictions of failure.

```
 Warning: Could not register destruction callback [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter@140f0e8] for attribute 'bean' because FacesRequestAttributes does not support such callbacks`
 Warning: Could not register destruction callback [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter@13f8471] for attribute 'courseDetailsBean' because FacesRequestAttributes does not support such callbacks
 Warning: Could not register destruction callback [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter@ce983a] for attribute 'bean' because FacesRequestAttributes does not support such callbacks
 Warning: Could not register destruction callback [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter@16bafa6] for attribute 'courseDetailsBean' because FacesRequestAttributes does not support such callbacks
```

Comment: What is your `BeanDAO` and `CourseDetailsDAO`?

Comment: @user6690200 Added.

Comment: `apc.getBean("courseDetailsDao");` doesn't return an instance of `CourseDetailsDAO`. What are you doing in there ?

Comment: @AxelH Yeah cause I put bean id as courseDetailsDao and class as BeanDAO. That was reason getting class cast though I wonder how it could be. Thank you so much for you're invaluable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your spring bean configuration file,have you declared BeanDao and CourseDetailsDao as beans by assessing id's are proper or not. which you have used for getting the object references.

```
CourseDetailsDAO helper = (CourseDetailsDAO) apc.getBean("courseDetailsDao");
```